# Angular4: No provider for t! after importing ng2-cache-service module

Tags: angular, caching, service, node-modules, provider

I've an angular 4 project with this node module for storing data: [DarthKurt/ng2-cache-service](https://github.com/DarthKurt/ng2-cache-service)

But I'm getting this error, only occurs after compiling with AOT:

*ng build --prod --aot*

```
ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: No provider for t!
```

I'm importing the cache service this way:

*app.module.ts*

```
...
import { CacheService } from 'ng2-cache-service';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    ...
  ],
  imports: [
    ...
  ],
  providers: [
    CacheService, {
    provide: APP_BASE_HREF, 
    useValue: '/app/ecommerce/'
  }],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

*app.component.ts*

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Response } from '@angular/http';
import { CacheService } from 'ng2-cache-service';
import 'rxjs/Rx';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
  providers: [ CacheService ]
})
export class AppComponent {

  constructor(public http: Http, public cache: CacheService) {}

  someFunc() {

    this.cache.set('test', 'works');
  }
 }
```

If I add the **CacheService** to the imports list in the *app.module.ts*, I'm always getting the following error:

```
ERROR in Unexpected value 'CacheService in /Users/rpereira/ecommerce/node_modules/ng2-cache-service/dist/src/services/cache.service.d.ts' imported by the module 'AppModule in /Users/rpereira/ecommerce/src/app/app.module.ts'. Please add a @NgModule annotation.

ERROR in ./src/main.ts
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './$$_gendir/app/app.module.ngfactory' in '/Users/rpereira/ecommerce/src'
 @ ./src/main.ts 4:0-74
 @ multi ./src/main.ts
```

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

Solved by switching the module to the original, [ng2-cache by Jackson88](https://github.com/Jackson88/ng2-cache), the errors only occurred in the forked one.